# How can I reload css styles when change windows width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize, reload

**How can I reload css styles when change windows width?**

I tried this but without success. A simple reload (`F5`) helps to correct the css tags.

```js
jQuery(function($){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var trigger = 1024;
    if (windowWidth < trigger) var smaller = true;
    else var bigger = true;

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if(windowWidth != $(window).width() &&
            ( ( smaller == true && $(window).width() > trigger ) ||
              ( bigger == true && $(window).width() < trigger )
            )
          ){
            window.location.reload(); 
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

---

**CSS example**

```css
.example {
    display: block;
    padding: 12px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

    .example {
        left: 80px;
        top: 80px;
        width: auto;
        padding: 8px;
    }

}
```

The original CSS styles had been modified by some `JS`, so I want to reload the original when the windows becomes smaller or bigger then 1024px.

Comment: Hi, what is a css tag ?

Comment: Sorry I meant css style. How can I reload the original css style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it works when you call the function with a timeout

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload();
},1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should hook your code (whatever you want to do, i didnt understand what you want to do very well actually) inside a [jquery resize event](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Here is an example:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $( "body" ).prepend( "<div>" + $( window ).width() + "</div>" );
});
```

Dont really see the why of using javascript or jquery to change css whenever viewport vidth gets risezed, generally its just better to use css media queries.